# error in a regression model using maximum likelihood

Tags: r, regression, mle

I'm trying to fit my data to a regression model as follows : `y=betaMu+betaA*Xa+betaD*Xd+si` where `si` is an error term with a normal distribution. I wrote the code below, where `phen[,2]` is data for `y` , `data.xa[,1]` is `Xa` and `data.xd[,1]` is `Xd`:

```
library(stats4)
ll <- function(betaM,betaA,betaD, mu, sigma){
  R= phen[,2]-betaM-betaA*data.xa[,1]-betaD*data.xd[,1]
  R = suppressWarnings(dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log=TRUE))
  -sum(log(R))
}
fit <- mle(ll,start = list(betaM = 1, betaA = 1,betaD=1 ,mu = -1, sigma=1.5))
```

but I keep getting this error :

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
>     initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In log(R) : NaNs produced

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: When you evaluate `ll()` at your initial values, what do you get?

Comment: well I'm very new to coding with R . when calling ll with different initial values for betaM , betaA &betaD I get this warning: In log(R) : NaNs produced

Comment: If @Gregor's comment doesn't clear things up for you, then we need to see a [mcve] before we can get any further ...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be computing the **logarithm of** the log-likelihood  (i.e., taking the log twice, presumably by accident). If any of your probability densities are < 1, then the log-density will be negative, and taking the log of the log-density will give `NaN`. Instead of

```
R = suppressWarnings(dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log=TRUE))
-sum(log(R))
```

, try

```
LL <- dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log=TRUE)
-sum(LL)
```

Also: (1) it's bad practice to suppress warnings unless you absolutely can't find a way to avoid them; (2) it's probably confusing to re-assign the value of `R` (although harmless in this case).